# GridView item is getting deselected on it's own

Tags: android, gridview

I think I got quite an unique problem where item in GridView is deselected after a couple of seconds.

I'm using custom BaseAdapter to populate the grid with ArrayList and I set different color for state_selected in background drawable for an item. Here is how I set it selected.

```
    //grid is a gridview initialised with Roboguice
    grid.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            view.setSelected(true);
            car_id = vehiclesList.get(i).getCarID();
            next_button.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

The problem is only with one tablet (Vonino Sirius QS), on others (Nexus 10 and no-name tablets) item stays selected.

Any ideas are appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: I'd say ... either the tablet customizes Android and blews it, the user has installed software that interferres the normal flow (ie. left/right edge swippers that are constantly capturing touch events), or the touchscreen quality is bad and delivers ghost touches (pretty common in el-cheapo tablets).

Comment: @rupps thank you for replying. Considering this is happening on our development tablet (costumers are getting theirs next week) I'm guessing ghost touches are to blame. This probably vary between different tablets of the same model as well right?

Comment: well it was just a wild guess, but I had a similar issue with a couple cheap tablets very prone to ghost touches around the edges, and the reasons are varied: static electricity, incorrect shielding, so yes, probably it will be very random, for example we have some amazon kindles that get ghost touches when plugged and charging, others when get a little hot.. at the end its obvious a $50 tablet is not expected to behave like an $500 one :)